# Why could the Android licensing check fail and would work after app reinstall?

Tags: android

I'm hoping to get some feedback to understand what could possibly be going wrong on my app with the licensing checks.

Lately I've been getting complains from users that my app has been failing the licensing checks. They have restarted their phones and also re-requested licensing checks but still would fail. Unfortunately I don't know what error code from the licensing checks was being returned... :(

The only way users have been able to get successful licensing checks was to reinstall the application.

Any insight why this could have been happening, specially all the sudden... I feel like since the new Google Play came out that this issues started happening.

Comment: Are you able to replicate this failure on your own device?

Comment: No, I haven't been able.